# Object #<Object> has no method 'addEventListener'

Tags: javascript

I have my canvas saved as an object but it won't let me add an eventListener because it creates this error:

```
Object #<Object> has no method 'addEventListener'
```

This is how i create the canvas:

```
    var i = 1;
    document.getElementById("G").innerHTML += '<canvas id="layer'+i+'" class="c" style="z-index:'+i+';"></canvas>'; 
    temp = document.getElementById('layer'+i);
    objname = 'canvas'+i;
    canvas[objname] = new Object();
    canvas[objname].ctx =  temp.getContext("2d");
```

Then i do:

```
canvas.canvas1.addEventListener("mousedown", fnc_test, false);
```

Any ideas why this is not allowed, or where I am going wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant

```
canvas[objname] = temp;
canvas[objname].ctx = temp.getContent("2d");
```

There is absolutely no reasoning for the `new Object` there...

Comment: The reason i had new obj was because i planned to have more than one canvas'

Comment: Saying that - it did seem to fix the problem! :D